# Using Twitter Bootstrap for simple responsive menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a simple navigation menu that is responsive, I've followed a few tutorials but when I preview my page, the design is completely different and the design isn't responsive. Can anyone help?
My code looks like this so far:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sara Cook</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Portfolio of my work">
<meta name="author" content="Sara Cook">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-th-list"></span>
</a>
    <a href="#" class="brand">Sara Cook</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse colapse">
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can check to see if the file is found by your browser, by opening developer tools (F12 in chrome or IE) and going to the network tab and reloading your page. It will have a link to that file and an HTTP status code to show whether it was found or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use both, just use either one,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Edited**

I believe you are using Bootstrap 3, so pls try the below code, see the [fiddle](http://bootply.com/92471) as well

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sara Cook</a><a class="navbar-toggle"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse colapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, still no luck though! I'm not getting any style around the buttons and the menu is vertical

Comment: Thank you, this has improved the style and it's now collapsing the menu, but when I make the browser size larger again, the menu disappears

Comment: its not disappears, its responsive design as per screen size (viewport), still you can see the menu by click on the collapsible icon.

Comment: the fiddle which I give, click on the mobile icon at the right side, so you can see the mobile view as well, and adjust that window size, then you can understand the difference.